# Display video in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I'm looking for a way to dynamically display a video in a modal pop-up, without being embedded to YouTube.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Play Video</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls>
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**YouTube Iframe**](https://jsfiddle.net/65breutv/)
 - Working example with embedded youtube video in iframe

[**Regular video**](https://jsfiddle.net/xb3v9c4u/)
 - Here I tried to use html video instead. The video gets the right `src` but it might be a problem with load timing.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why don't use the html "video" component instead of iframe ?

Comment: @LéoR. Look at the second fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xb3v9c4u/

Comment: Isn't there is a working example already?

Comment: Tried making it work with html5 video, but can't, otherwise I wouldn't make this post.. Well it almost works, used the YouTube iframe embed as example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything looks good, you are just missing `$(theModal + ' video').load();`. You have to load the external video if you are setting src runtime.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' video').load();
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Play Video</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls width="100%">
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/scxf7mzv/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting src on the source element. Set it directly on the video element. If you modify it to `$(theModal + ' video').attr('src', videoSRCauto);` then it works like you would expect. Alternatively, you would probably want to create the source element with the src already set.

Comment: Are there any consequences by setting it directly on the `video` element?

Comment: Nope. The source tags are mainly to support a use case of different videos in different formats.