# Offline video modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a video modal to run on an offline invirenment.
I have tried to use the answer in this question...
[Display video in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481655/display-video-in-modal)

```
`$(function() {
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' video').load();
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});`

`<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-    toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Play Video</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls width="100%">
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

The videos (video1), (video2) ect. are on a local network, as are the HTML,CSS,JS,JQUERY folders and files.

This works fine when connected to the internet... but does not work offline.

I can find the portions in the css file to copy out. (modal, btn etc.)
`<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/modal.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/buttons.css"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </head>`

My understanding of javascript is limited...
I have tried to download the js files, but I cannot find the portions in the js files to copy and make this work without linking back to the internet files. And the files do not seem to work when linking to them in the same folder as the HTML or a seperate JS folder. (I have an audio player that is linked to a leftplayer.js file in a JS folder and it works).

Is there some script that I can use to make this work? Also when I close the modal by xing out... the video continues to play the audio.

Comment: If you put all these resources local, then I don't see what exactly could be _"linking back to the internet files"_ - AFAIK, neither Bootstrap nor jQuery have any such external dependencies hardcoded.

Comment: _"Also when I close the modal by xing out... the video continues to play the audio."_ - because the modal will only be set to display:none. You will have subscribe to the modal close event, and then pause the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the `bootstrap.min.css` from: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css and `bootstrap.min.js` from
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js

Include them in your web page like this

```
 <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Please include the path to the files above in case essential.

Now you may modify your `js` like this

```
$(function() {
    $(".video").click(function() {
      var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
      $(theModal + ' video').load();
      $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function() {
        $(theModal + ' video')[0].pause(); 
        $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', '');
      });
    });
  });
```

And I think you are good to go.

**Modified Code**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".video").click(function() {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
      videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video");
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    $(theModal + ' video').load();
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function() {
      $(theModal + ' video')[0].pause();
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', '');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Play Video</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls width="100%">
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Modified the code and placed it in the Main Response to you using jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry I do not see how to use jsfiddle to show the codes that I have tried

Comment: Hey @user22318059, if the code works for you then Please accept the answer by clicking on the Arrow Mark. Also, Click for UpVote

Comment: the answer does not work offline yet

Comment: I have tried your answer. However it does not load the video unles you connect online with [https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js].
with jquery.min.js downloaded to a folder it gets an error "e t not defined". Note I need to run this in an invirement with no internet.

Comment: Did you not read the Text on the top of the answer? Download all files as necessary and `include` them the webpage by indicating the path to the files.

Comment: You can download the bootstrap.min.css from: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js from https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js

These do work offline. You did not include - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js in your list to download... It does not load the video without this also.

Comment: I did download and link to this file... although when I run it offline the Firefox Inspector shows an error that e and t are not defined in jquery.min.js and does not load the video.
It does work when includeing linking it to the online path that requires an internet connection. For some reason I am not able to get jquery.min.js to work offline in this script application... although I have it linked in other script applications to an earlier version and it works.

Comment: Did you show the `path` to the file locations correctly?. I need to see how you have setup your folder system and the linking in the `<head>` statements in relation to this htm/html page. For example, if you have put all `.css` files in a folder named `bootstrap\css` then the statement for each reference in `<head>` should be like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/modal.css">. I have shown only one. do it for all include `.js`.

Comment: Firefox Inspector sees them and refers to them when throwing the error message.
Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined... load   jQuery... then refering to the line... '$(theModal + ' video').load();'... everything loads- the modal- the controls- just not the video.
This is my links to these files... 
'<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="../../js/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../js/3.3.4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>'

Comment: Hey, Are your sure about the path definition like this `../../css/` and `../../js`? It means to go two folders up and then look for the file in that folder.  If not then just move the css and js files to the same folder where the `htm` or `html` exists and remove the `../../`. or use the full path to the files.  I have tried the code on `FireFox`. It works fine for me.

Comment: OK... found the problem... after you saying that it worked for you - I downloaded jquery.min.js again and replaced the one I had... the first one must have been corrupted on download. and yes ../../ are because my js and css folders are in my root directory. Every thing now works.
Thank you for your time.